# Video editor suggestion

Tags: software-recommendation, freeware

I'm new here.
I'm looking for a easy-to-use video editor, like windows movie maker but with a couple of more tools like: adding videos over a video and adding two or more lines of text simultaneously appearing with different effects. I'm using Windows 7 and the software must be free. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good open source Video Editors?](http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions/2274/good-open-source-video-editors)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start here: [10 free video editors](http://www.akascope.com/2011/07/15/free-video-editing-software/) <sup>[*mirror*](https://web.archive.org/web/20140301015804/http://www.akascope.com/2011/07/15/free-video-editing-software)</sup>.

Keep in mind that free video editors are very simple and do not have many effects. 
I recommend you to buy inexpensive video editing software, like Sony Movie Studio or Cyberlink PowerDirector. Take a look at this list of consumer [video editors](http://vegasaur.com/video-editing-software) <sup>[*mirror*](https://web.archive.org/web/20150907103605/http://vegasaur.com/video-editing-software)</sup>.